# xPath Text Contains Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to select an element based on its text contents. I am using XPath to achieve this.

I am just puzzled as this should work?

```
WebElement link = obj.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Notifications')]"));
```

[image: gfg]

I'll even copy the HTML code:

```
<div class="linkWrap noCount">Notifications&nbsp;<span class="count _5wk0 hidden_elem uiSideNavCountText">(<span class="countValue fsm">0</span><span class="maxCountIndicator"></span>)</span></div>
```

The div element has the words "Notifications" inside it. So why doesn't it work.

Go to this page on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/settings

Use this [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-and-xpath-checker/aoinfihhckpkkcpholfhmkeplbhddipe?hl=en) to highlight any area via xPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with the help of some amazing people in this community.

Ok, so my element was in an iFrame.

[image]

In order to access the element, I must first access the iFrame

```
WebElement iframe = obj.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@tabindex='-1']"));
    
obj.driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space before the word Notifications:

```
WebElement link = obj.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Notifications')]"));
```

You should also add a wait for element before trying to find the element:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Notifications')]"));

WebElement link = obj.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Notifications')]"));
```

Comment: Opps! That shouldn't have been there. When I tested it I'm pretty positive I didn't have it in there. I have tried it without space. It still doesn't appear to be working

Comment: Follow the last part of my question. The exact place on Facebook where I am referencing too. Then use the chrome extension to highlight any area via Xpath

Comment: When I copied the code into Stackoverflow there was a line break at that point. I might have tried to intend some of it or something. But the code I tested with, did not have a space like that

Comment: You don't need a chrome extension to test xpath. the dev tools do just fine.

Comment: Yes an error: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(text(), 'Notifications')]"}

Comment: Every time the chrome extension doesn't highlight it. To show it's there. Then I also get an error in my Java.

Comment: WebElement web = obj.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Notifications')]"));
  
  System.out.println(web.getLocation());

Comment: The chrome extension actually highlights the area on the screen. Not just in the console and HTML.

Comment: The page is already fulled loaded. That wait makes absolutely no difference. Again, please check the chrome extension. Nothing is highlighted. When using developer tools. I see it selects the line above the words "Notifications". However, like the Chrome extension shows and executing that xPath in practice. It doesn't appear to work. It does not find it.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're tyring to solve? Clicking on the element? Or some other function?

Comment: I want to reference the element. From there I can find its X and Y location. Then pass this over to my Windows Application. This will perform human-like non-linear mouse movements. So it will move on to the element and click it as a human would.

Comment: Many elements in Facebook I can't seem to reference. This is one example. From the outside, it seems I should be able to... However, in practice it doesn't work.

Comment: Like I keep saying, try the Chrome extension. Try an xPath you know will 100% work, so see how it highlights the area. Then try the xPath I have above. It doesn't highlight anything. Then in my Java, the element is not found.

Comment: you can move the mouse via selenium and you certainly can click.  I think you have not fully explained your problem in the question above.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. However, you can't perform non-linear mouse movements. I am training a bot to be human-like. You can only move the mouse, like I need to, with a windows application. (AutoIt specifically) Not in selenium or any web browser. It is impossible. In selenium, you can only move a mouse from A to B... Not move it as a human would.

Comment: This is beside the point. Whatever I do after referencing an element is not important. First, I must be able to reference the element.

Comment: I simply just want to successfully reference the element via the xPath I provide in the question. That's it. Can you try it on your end? As it's really weird behavior. Why can't I successfully reference it without flagging an error in selenium? It states the element can not be found.

Comment: The chrome extension also states the element can not be found. Using the xPath in Chrome Developer tools does highlight a line. However, the chrome extension and Selenium say it doesn't exist.