# Unable to locate element | xPath | Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to reference and then click an element on a web page.

This is the web page: https://www.facebook.com/settings

This is the element:

[image]

```
<div class="linkWrap noCount">Notifications&nbsp;<span class="count _5wk0 hidden_elem uiSideNavCountText">(<span class="countValue fsm">0</span><span class="maxCountIndicator"></span>)</span></div>
```

It's a DIV which contains the word "Notifications"

We should be able to reference with a simple xPath. Such as `//div[contains(text(), 'Notifications')]`

However, it doesn't seem to work.

A [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-and-xpath-checker/aoinfihhckpkkcpholfhmkeplbhddipe?hl=en) I use says the element doesn't exist.

[image]

My code can't find the element.

Here is my Java code using Selenium web driver.

```
// Navigate to page
obj.driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/settings");        

// Write to console where we are
System.out.println(obj.driver.getCurrentUrl());

// Wait | Plenty of time for the page to load
Thread.sleep(5000);     

obj.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Notifications')]")).click();
```

Here is the error:

[image: sdsad]

It is so very strange! Any ideas on why I can't reference the element, or why the xPath doesn't exsist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xPath Text Contains Selenium Web Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559799/xpath-text-contains-selenium-web-driver)

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow scraping. It's against their TOS.

Comment: JeffC I'm not scraping or anything of that sort. I'm simply automating some simple tasks that are very routine.

Comment: DMart I have an answer below. It is a very plausible reason for why I am experiencing this behavior. I will test it out

Comment: DMart the answer below is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element is within an `iframe`.

If you scroll up from where you are you'll see this:
[image]

For selenium you need to switch frames in order to access the elements within them

I've not tried it for your site yet - but you switch frames with:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(1); // by index
//<or> 
driver.switchTo().frame("id of the element"); //by id
//<or> 
driver.switchTo().frame(element); // be element
```

Then, when ready switch back to the main page/frame with:

```
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Have a look at the frames section of the [selenium docs](https://www.selenium.dev/docs/site/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/#frames-and-iframes) here

Comment: Amazing thank you! This was the issue. I was able to select the frame through this: WebElement iframe = obj.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@tabindex='-1']"));
  
  obj.driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);